# When using Bootstrap 4's Grid automatic column sizing on breakpoints, they get ignored permanently once the browser is made smaller

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

As the title explains, I have a simple row which contains either one or two columns. They are given an explicit column size at the `xs` breakpoint and `col-md`.

It works completely as expected, apart from once the browser gets resized (only smaller) the `col-md` get instantly ignored, regardless of whether its breakpoint is met or not.

The only solution to correct the sizing is to refresh the page.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div id="revenue" class="panel-body text-center"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div id="wc-conv" class="panel-body text-center">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea what is causing this, nor if there are any solutions.

Comment: It works exactly as expected. The `col-md` are stacking vertically on screen widths less than 768px. The `col-xs-12` does nothing since the `xs` infix is no longer exist and col-12 is implied. https://www.codeply.com/go/cTxE9v3MV4

Comment: @Zim as detailed in my comment on the below answer, this was an oversight but does not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

that's why bootstrap 4 doesn't have .col-xs grid. Instead of .col-xs-6, it’s now .col-6.
so, try it like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div id="revenue" class="panel-body text-center"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div id="wc-conv" class="panel-body text-center">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-md">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div id="revenue" class="panel-body text-center"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-md">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div id="wc-conv" class="panel-body text-center">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for identifying my oversight! Although it does not remedy my issue. When the page loads the 2 columns are evenly sized  to allow both to sit side by side. If I was to resize the browser even slightly and make the window smaller.  My columns immediately become full width, and stay like so until a refresh.